# C# Sort Array by property based on key array

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, comparison

Say I have the following 2 arrays

```
string[] keys = new string[]{"Annalee Call","Bishop","Ash"};

MyClass[] vals = new MyClass[]{
    new MyClass(){name = "Ash"},
    new MyClass(){name = "Annalee Call"},
    new MyClass(){name = "Bishop"}
};
```

What is the best way to sort the MyClass array by name based on the keys array without resorting to for loops?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it would be as follows:

```
var sorted = vals.OrderBy(s => Array.IndexOf(keys, s.name)).ToArray();
```

Note that this algorithm is asymptotically very slow: it has `O(N^2*LogN)` complexity. To bring it back to the "normal" `O(N*LogN)`, prepare a lookup dictionary for finding indexes, like this:

```
var keyDict = keys.Select((v,i)=>new {v,i}).ToDictionary(p=>p.v, p=>p.i);
var sorted = vals.OrderBy(s => keyDict[s.name]).ToArray();
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you for the additional information and providing the lookup dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I would use this approach to do the sorting. It handles the case if values in `vals` are missing from the `keys` list.

```
var rank =
    keys
        .Select((v, n) => new { Value = v, Rank = n, })
        .ToLookup(vn => vn.Value, vn => vn.Rank);

var query =
    from v in vals
    orderby rank[v.name]
        .DefaultIfEmpty(int.MaxValue)
        .First()
    select v;
```

Otherwise it is very similar to dasblinkenlight's answer.

Comment: You make a good point in checking for the existence of each key.  In my current situation a check is not needed, but pretty much every other scenario should implement a key check.